# Matching items in a string

Tags: python, list, matching, organizer

I am trying to work with a output I am receiving from a job application database, I need each account information organized into a list but I am not sure how match the applicants startdates because it starts at #1 but sometimes it's to be paired with a different number depending if the person was hired or not.

For example startdate#1 needs to be paired with name#3, and startdate#2 needs to be paired with name#4.

**What I am starting with:**

```
FirstName#1 = Joe | FirstName#2 = Michael | FirstName#3 = Harold | FirstName#4 = John | LastName#1 = Miles | LastName#2 = Gomez | LastName#3 = Hall | LastName#4 = Hancock | Hired#1 = False | Hired#2 = False | Hired#3 = True | Hired#4 = True | StartDate#1 = 10/31/2018 | StartDate#2 = 10/25/2018 |
```

**Need to output:**

```
[['Joe','Miles','False'], ['Michael','Gomez','False'], ['Harold','Hall','True','10/31/2018'], ['John','Hancock','True','10/25/2018']]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: This question is far too broad. If you show us what you have tried so far, we can better help you. Just copy and paste your source code (as text) here and press "Ctrl + K" to have the whole code indented by 4 spaces and thus formatted just the way has to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may do this as below: (you may want to read about python 'exec')

```
import re

db_output = """FirstName#1 = Joe | FirstName#2 = Michael | FirstName#3 = Harold |        FirstName#4 = John | LastName#1 = Miles | LastName#2 = Gomez | LastName#3 = Hall | LastName#4 = Hancock | Hired#1 = False | Hired#2 = False | Hired#3 = True | Hired#4 = True | StartDate#1 = 10/31/2018 | StartDate#2 = 10/25/2018 |"""

# define the keys
keys = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Hired', 'StartDate']

# create empty dict with name in keys
for key in keys:
    exec('{} = dict()'.format(key))

# parse and build dicts
for data in db_output.split(' |'):
    data = data.strip()
    if data == '':
        continue

    reobj = re.search('(\S+)#(\d+)\s+=(.*)', data)
    if reobj:
        key = reobj.group(1).strip()
        num = int(reobj.group(2))
        value = reobj.group(3).strip()

        print key, num, value
        exec('{}[num] = value'.format(key))

# get the inexes for FirstName and sort it
exec('firstname_indexes = {}.keys()'.format(keys[0]))
firstname_indexes = sorted(firstname_indexes)

# get all local variables (required due to usage 'exec')
local = locals()

# variable to collect all data
output = list()

# Start date starts with 1
startdate_track = 1

# use firstname indexes and track start date, create a tmp list and
# then append to output
for fn_index in firstname_indexes:
    tmp = list()
    for key in keys:
        if key == 'StartDate':
            if tmp[-1] == 'True':
                tmp.append(local[key][startdate_track])
                startdate_track += 1
            output.append(tmp)
        else:
            tmp.append(local[key][fn_index])

print output
```

Output:

```
[['Joe', 'Miles', 'False'], ['Michael', 'Gomez', 'False'], ['Harold', 'Hall', 'True', '10/31/2018'], ['John', 'Hancock', 'True', '10/25/2018']]
```